# How can I show partially colored text in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, visualization, matlab-figure

I am trying to color some alphabets in a string based on input alphabet given.
Can anyone suggest me how to achieve it ? As I am new to this.

Suppose that I have the following string: "AUSTRALIA"

**INPUT**: A
**OUTPUT**: (A in red)'A'USTR(A in red)'A'LI(A in red)'A'

Comment: Where do you want to output? MATLAB command line? GUI? Web page?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Show us the code you have so far, and consider changing the question title to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to show it as text on axes  (GUI), use the **text** command and Latex formatted strings

```
text('string','{\color{red} A}ustralia')
```

You can read about Latex commands [here](http://www.latex-project.org/).
Alternatively, there is an undocumented functionality for some UI controls, mentioned in Yair Altmans [great website](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/html-support-in-matlab-uicomponents/).

That is the way to do it (Taken directly from his site)

```
uicontrol('Style','list', 'Position',[10,10,70,70], 'String', ...
{'<HTML><FONT color="red">Hello</Font></html>', 'world', ...
 '<html><font style="font-family:impact;color:green"><i>What a', ...
 '<Html><FONT color="blue" face="Comic Sans MS">nice day!</font>'});
```

In order to actually find the letters instances, use the **strrep** command.

```
strrep(lower('Australia'),'a','{\color{red}a}')
```

There is a flaw here, related to capital letter, I am sure that you can work it out!