# Matlab multiple colors in annotation textbox

Tags: matlab, textbox, annotations

I'm trying to plot two sets of data with their respective regressions in one figure, and then I want to annotate the plot with p-values for each regression with annotations in colors corresponding to the plot.  I currently have, in brief:

```
plot(year, rawdata, 'bo'); plot(year, fitraw, 'b-');
plot(year, adjusted, 'go'); plot(year, fitadjust, 'g-');
textraw = sprintf('%s %g', 'p = ', statsraw.p(2));
textadj = sprintf('%s %g', 'p = ', statsadj.p(2));
annotation('textbox', [0 0 .15 .15], 'String', {textraw, textadj});
```

I saw a suggestion elsewhere to use something along the lines of '{\color{blue}}' but I can't figure out where to put it and how to make both the string "p = " and the variable for the p-value both show up in the color, and then do all of the second line in green.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are recalling is using Latex to format portions of text, [which is answered in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810815/how-can-i-show-partially-colored-text-in-matlab). I don't think that this works in annotations though (and I don't have MATLAB to try it, but feel free to give it a shot).

You'll need to change the annotation textbox properties [[Official MATLAB docs]](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotationtextboxproperties.html) and have two seperate textboxes as follows:

```
annotation('textbox', 'Position', [0 0 .15 .15], 'String', ['p = ' num2str(statsraw.p(2))], 'Color', 'b' );
annotation('textbox', 'Position', [0 0 .25 .15], 'String', ['p = ' num2str(statsadj.p(2))], 'Color', 'g' );
```

(You'll have to change the position to something sensible)